# Set EditContext asynchronously in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a page, that loads a model in OnParametersSet. This model can be edited in a form. This works perfectly when I provide the model to EditForm directly via `Model="ViewModel.Something"`. However I cannot make it work using EditContext, because EditContext wants to be initialized in OnParametersSet.

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.
System.InvalidOperationException: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.OnParametersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

Code:

```
@inject SomeViewModel ViewModel

@if(ViewModel.Something != null)
{
    <EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="@Submit">
        // ...
    </EditForm>
}

@code
{
    [Parameter] public string? SomethingId { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    private EditContext editContext { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => StateHasChanged();

        ViewModel.LoadSomething.Subscribe(_ => editContext = new(ViewModel!.Something));
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.OnParametersSet();

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomethingId))
        {
            ViewModel.Query = new LoadSomethingQuery(SomethingId);
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

I want to make use of EditContext's IsModified property. Therefore I need to use EditContext instead of Model. But it does not work if EditContext is initialized after page initialization. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: off topic, but be careful with `+=` and or `.Subscribe()` to long living objects. If your `SomeViewModel` is not Transient service (is scoped or singleton = long living object), you have a memory leak.

Comment: @Liero thanks for pointing that out. SomeViewModel is transient in my case.

Comment: @UpCat - I don't see anything async here, that is strange. You normally await the Loading part and then you don't need or want events.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I left it out as "off topic", because I am using reactiveui for the ViewModel stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One option would be to check editContext for nulls:

  ```
  @if(editContext != null)
  {
      <EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="@Submit">
          // ...
      </EditForm>
  }
  ```
- Another option - Create the EditContext in ctor or OnInitialized and replace it with fresh instance in OnParametesSet:

  ```
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
      base.OnInitialized();
      editContext = new EditContext(...);
      ...
  }

  protected override void OnParametersSet()
  {
      base.OnParametersSet();

      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomethingId))
      {
          ViewModel.Query = new LoadSomethingQuery(SomethingId);
          ...
          editContext = new EditContext(...);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Another option: `@ref="editForm"` and use `editForm.EditContext`

Comment: @HenkHolterman when setting editForm via editForm.EditContext I get a warning "EditContext should not be set outside of its component".

Comment: ?  You should not need to 'set' it, what I meant was just a 'get'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I don't recommend it, since the editContext can change (it changes on Render, when Model property is updated, which is done after StateHasChanged). In this case you probably want fresh EditContext after each LoadSomethingQuery()...

Comment: @Liero - not clear what 'it' is here, I wouldn't store the EditContext when I have access to the EditForm.

Comment: it = using EditForm reference in order to subscribe for EditContext events, since their lifetime is different. Here is what I mean: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GwaelnEt27HQh5y623